# How to configure Crashlytics Android Beta Distribution process?

Tags: android, google-fabric, crashlytics-beta

I have noticed that apps installed with Crashlytics Android Beta Distribution always reinstall app from scratch. Like all my preferences, databases, etc data get lost after each update of the app. Is there any way to configure the update process? Instead of a clean install to have it updating app the same way Play Market performs its updates.

Comment: Seriously? I used it time ago and the app was always just updated.

Answer (score 1):

When updating builds in Beta, a normal update should happen and non of your data should be lost.